# Youtube Data API v3: Update video title get 403 Forbidden with `"reason": "forbidden"` without explanation

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

When using [Youtube's Data API's update video title API request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) a 403 forbidden error is returned.

The code used is:

```
SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
]

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"

store = file.Storage("youtube-token.json")
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets("credentials.json", SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, credentials=creds
)

# other API calls work with THIS service, i.e.:service.playlistItems().list(...) is OK.
# but this fails:

request = service.videos().update(
    part="id,snippet",
    body={
        "id": video_id,
        "snippet": {
            "title": title,
        },
    },
)
request.execute()
```

The returned error is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "youtube.video",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The documentation is pretty vague regarding `"reason": "forbidden"`.

All access to videos was approved via OAuth.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using an incorrect video ID!

In the returned list from `service.playlistItems().list(...)`, I have used `items["items"][0]["id"]` which gives the `playlistItem` id instead of `items["items"][0]["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]` which gives the `videoId`!

Comment: THANK YOU! I was so lost I couldn't find any solution.  This worked!